# Stopping infinite loop on mouseleave or mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was experimenting on something which executes a function continuously when the mouse is down. I got it to loop infinitely which is exactly what I wanted but I cannot seem to stop that loop anymore.

I tried doing :-

```
$(document).on("mouseup mouseout",".someclass",function(){ loop(false) } );
```

which takes the false argument and should stop the loop. But the loop just goes on infinitely causing the page to crash. I want that infinite loop to stop whenever some event is called, be it mouseup, mouseout, mouseleave whichever.

My attempt so far:- http://jsfiddle.net/ZQTvN/

**Do realize that this will crash your browser.**

Comment: what is your end goal? Perhaps we can suggest a better appraoch

Comment: My goal is to trigger a function on an event call continuously whilst that event is happening (like keypress, mousedown) and stop the function immediately after the event is over.

Comment: Well, I sort of mean what will this function do? Like - monitor elapsed time user spends hovering over images, etc. But even without specifics, perhaps a better idea is to set a boolean on mouseenter, or whatever event, and have your loop function constantly running with a condition based on that boolean. so `setInterval( function(){ if(some_var){ ... } },500)` then set some_var to true on event and false on opposite event.

Comment: Aha. That's actually a brilliant alternative for what I'm trying to achieve. 
Here's what I have so far. Any one who can tweak this and make it better will be marked as the correct one.

http://jsfiddle.net/shriek/ZQTvN/5/

Comment: Also, to answer your question @KaiQing the function just checks the value of an input field on the page and limits the number to certain range. <input type="number"/> to be more precise.

Comment: Also, I just realized that there is <input type="number" min="0"/> attribute. *sigh*. Oh well, I learned something though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter the code to use a flag and a setTimeout to achieve what you want:

A tight loop like this (busy-loop) will block any input from the browser so it is basically unable to parse the event queue, ie. browser gets locked.

By implementing a setTimout to do the loop you will allow the browser to queue other events as well, which you would need to detect when to stop it.

If you call your loop with an argument each time you will in fact only re-trigger it multiple times. When you call with false flag the flag will be local to that call and do nothing with the other loops that has started as they don't have access to this locallized flag.

So one approach is to put the flag outside(common flag, global scope):

**[MODIFIED FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQTvN/7/)**

Example:

```
var doLoop = false;

function loopy() {
    if (doLoop === true) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(doLoop);
            loopy();
        }, 11);
    }

};
$(document).on("mousedown", ".classy", function () {
    doLoop = true;
    loopy();
});
$(document).on("mouseup mouseout", ".classy", function () {
    doLoop = false;
});
```

Now you can see the loop runs while holding the mouse down, and stops when released etc.