# Looping over AJAX requested images on mouseover, stopping the loop on mouseleave

Tags: javascript, ajax, onmouseover

I've got a grid of models, each consisting of a link, image and name. On mouseenter, I'm looking to replace the src-attribute of the hovered image every second by a list of AJAX loaded images in a loop. On mouseleave, the original image should revert and the loop should stop.

```
<div class="c-grid c-grid--models">
    <a href="#link-to-model" class="c-model" data-id="1">
        <figure class="c-model__wrap">
            <img src="http://placeholder.image" data-original="http://lazyloaded.image" class="c-model__image" />
            <figcaption class="c-model__name">Model 1</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
    <a href="#link-to-model" class="c-model" data-id="2">
        <figure class="c-model__wrap">
            <img src="http://placeholder.image" data-original="http://lazyloaded.image" class="c-model__image" />
            <figcaption class="c-model__name">Model 2</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
</div>
```

The images are lazyloaded when they appear in the viewport. They are stored in the data-original tag. Below is the script that I got working.

```
    var _brakes = 1;
    var _timer1 = null;
    var _timer2 = null;
    var _data = null;
    $('.c-grid--models .c-model').hover(
        function() {
            _brakes = 0;
            _id     = $(this).attr('data-id');
            $image = $('img',$(this));
            var $this = $(this);
            _timer1 = setTimeout(function (){
                $this.request('onHover', {
                    data : {
                        id : _id
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        _data = $.parseJSON(data.result);
                        $.each(_data, function(i, new_image) {
                            _timer2 = setTimeout(function (){
                                if(_brakes == 0) {
                                    $image.attr('src', new_image);
                                } else {
                                    clearTimeout(_timer1);
                                    clearTimeout(_timer2);
                                    _data = null;
                                    _timer1 = null;
                                    _timer2 = null;
                                }
                            }, i * 1000);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }, 1000);
        }, function() {
            _brakes = 1;
            $image = $('img',$(this));
            $image.attr('src',$image.attr('data-original'));
            clearTimeout(_timer1);
            clearTimeout(_timer2);
            _data = null;
            _timer1 = null;
            _timer2 = null;
        }
    );
```

Problems:

1. The loop stops when the last image has been reached. I would like to keep looping untill the mouseleave event is fired
2. Upon mouseleave and mouse(re)enter, the imagerotation speeds up and behaves erraticly. It seems the first loop hasn't properly stopped.
3. The images of one model get crossed with those of another model when hovering back and forth.

Note: `$(this).request('onHover'...` is part of the October CMS Ajax framework. It executes a PHP function that returns a JSON array of all the images of the model that currently is hovered.

Can anyone help with this issue? It might be that the logic I used is not right. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Related:

[Stopping infinite loop on mouseleave or mouseout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192136/stopping-infinite-loop-on-mouseleave-or-mouseout)

Comment: What is `$(this).request`

Comment: Hi, just edited it. It is part of October CMS, documentation https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/javascript-api

Comment: The `$(this)` in `$(this).request` is not the same as in `$(this).attr('data-id')` because of how your `setTimeout` is set up.  Try `var $this = $(this)` above the setTimeout and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This shows already some improvement: problem with speeding up images is solved. But I've seen that when I hover back and forth over more containers, the requests get mixed up: pictures of model A end up in the sequence of model B etc... I tried putting the timers in global variables and clearing them when the brakes are on / on mouseleave. Any further suggestions? Updates the code part.

Comment: What is `$this.request('onHover'...)` returning? A list of all images? One image?

Comment: Hi, the request returns a JSON array of all the images of the hovered model, stored in a "result" key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good friend helped me out and solved the problem for me.

We took a different approach, storing the total amount of images and the current image in data-attributes on each html element.

Instead of returning the whole array of images, we now rotate over the images one per one.

New HTML:

```
<div class="c-grid c-grid--models">
    <a href="#link-to-model" class="c-model" data-id="1" data-image-counter="5" data-current-image="0">
        <figure class="c-model__wrap">
            <img src="http://placeholder.image" data-original="http://lazyloaded.image" class="c-model__image" />
            <figcaption class="c-model__name">Model 1</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
    <a href="#link-to-model" class="c-model" data-id="2" data-image-counter="5" data-current-image="0">
        <figure class="c-model__wrap">
            <img src="http://placeholder.image" data-original="http://lazyloaded.image" class="c-model__image" />
            <figcaption class="c-model__name">Model 2</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
</div>
```

New JavaScript:

```
$(function() {

    var hoveredItem = null;

    // Don't fire on touch devices
    if($('.c-grid--models').length && !Modernizr.touchevents) {

        $('.c-grid--models .c-model').hover(
            function() { // mouseenter

                $(this).data("mouse-hover", true);

                if(!$(this).data("is-busy") ) {
                    $(this).data("is-busy", true);
                    GetNextImage($(this));
                }
                // get next image with delay
            }, function() { // mouseleave
                // set original image and stop loop
                $(this).data("mouse-hover", false);
                var orignalimage = $("img",$(this)).data("original");
                $("img", $(this)).attr("src", orignalimage);
            }
        );
    }

    function GetNextImage(imageContainer) {
        hoveredItem = imageContainer;

        if (parseInt(imageContainer.data("image-counter")) <= 1) return;

        setTimeout( function() {

            if (imageContainer.data("mouse-hover") == true)
            {

                imageContainer.data("current-image", parseInt(imageContainer.data("current-image")) + 1);

                $(this).request("onHover", {
                    data: {
                        id: imageContainer.data("id"),
                        image_id: imageContainer.data("current-image")
                    }, success: function (data) {

                        // Reset
                        var total = parseInt(imageContainer.data("image-counter"))-1;
                        var current = parseInt(imageContainer.data("current-image"));
                        if (current >= total) imageContainer.data("current-image", 0);

                        // async callback finished. no longer busy
                        if (imageContainer.data("mouse-hover") == true) {
                            var _data = $.parseJSON(data.result);
                            $('img',imageContainer).attr('src', _data);

                            GetNextImage(imageContainer); //Loop
                        } else {
                            imageContainer.data("is-busy", false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                imageContainer.data("is-busy", false);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if (hoveredItem != null) {
            hoveredItem.data("mouse-hover", false);

        }
    });
});
```

Important to note is that on scrolling does not always fire onmouseleave. So upon scrolling we cancel the image rotation until the user mouseenters once more.

I hope this can be useful. If somethings are not clear, just comment below and I'll update the answer.