# capture setTimeout timerID when setTimeout is used in an if loop

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm using setTimeout to create a pause in a loop (on mouseenter) and need to capture the timer ID so it can be stopped on mouseleave.

I thought that would be a simple task… before I tried to code it.

I have a gallery of thumbnails and on hovering over a thumbnail I want to cycle though a series of images (in an endless loop); kind of like a mini-carousel. I achieve this with the common method of swapping out the thumbnail’s source file path; I capture and store the thumbnail’s file path, loop through an array of images then replace the original thumbnail on mouseleave. Nothing complicated.

I coded this up and everything worked fine except on mouseenter the function looped through the entire array of images no matter how briefly the mouse hovered. I eventually discovered that you can’t actually pause a function or stop it but by wrapping it in a setTimeout and using a boolean flag you can create that effect. This is the answer I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/19192399 by user1693593, it’s really simple and works really well.

```
    var doLoop = false;

    function loopy() {
        if (doLoop === true) {
            setTimeout(function () {
            // code to loop through array of images
            loopy();
            }, 11);
        }
    };
```

I'm using jQuery's hover method to set the flag.

```
    $(".thumbnails").hover(function() {
        doLoop = true;
    }, function() {
        doLoop = false;
    });
```

So I coded that up and it worked perfectly when you hover over the first thumbnail but when you move to a new thumbnail it all goes haywire. I figured out this was because the first timeout wasn’t being cancelled and subsequent timeouts were interfering with it (and each other). I can see from various Stack Overflow questions that this is a common problem. I discovered that setTimeout returns an ID that you need to capture if you want to cancel it with clearTimeout.

So I found an example on MDN [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) whereby you store the timeout ID in a variable. It looked simple enough so I coded that up and it worked perfectly. I can see in the console all the timeouts being set (with unique IDs) and cancelled as the mouse moves over the thumbnails… but now I can’t get the loop to work.

I can’t understand why this is so complicated in JavaScript, surely something like this is a common requirement.

Can someone please take pity on a relative newbie and explain how I can code user1693593's example so that it works when mousing over multiple elements. I don’t mind if it uses setTimeout or setInterval.

Please don’t mark this as a duplicate – I’ll understand if someone does – but I’ve been all over Stack Overflow (plus MDN and W3Schools) and I can’t find an example that specifically answers this question, certainly not one that I can understand anyway.

Comment: Why aren't you using `setInterval`?

Comment: so set it to another global variable...

Comment: @nickzoum I'm just trying to get it working at the moment but I may well switch to setInterval then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the reference somewhere and cancel it.

```js
var timer = null

function addOne (elem) {
  elem.textContent = (+elem.textContent + .1).toFixed(1)
}


$(".foo")
  .on("mouseenter", function () {
    var elem = this
    timer = window.setInterval(function () { addOne(elem) }, 100)
  }).on("mouseleave", function () {
    if (timer) window.clearInterval(timer)
  })
```

```css
div.foo {
  width:100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">1</div>
<div class="foo">1</div>
<div class="foo">1</div>
<div class="foo">1</div>
<div class="foo">1</div>
```

Comment: Just a couple of questions. 1) are you using null as the initial value of the timer variable so that the if statement works the first time a thumbnail is hovered over. 2) why have you chosen to use .on rather than .hover? is there some kind of performance benefit? I notice .on works on child elements too.

Comment: 1) because you should declare a variable 2) hover is just a helper method, calls the same events says it right in the documentation of hover.

Comment: Well this isn't much like the original code -- by user1693593 -- but it's succinct and works perfectly so I'm accepting it as the answer. Thanks for your help and patience @epascarello (and you too @James).

Answer (score -1):

Just keep track of the element that’s currently doing the loop instead of a boolean true/false.

```
var loopEl;

function loopy() {
    if (loopEl) {
        setTimeout(function () {
        // code to loop through array of images
        // do something with loopEl
        loopy();
        }, 11);
    }
};

$(".thumbnails").hover(function() {
    loopEl = this;
}, function() {
    loopEl = false;
});
```

Comment: what is the condition for the if statement. Also loopEl (on mouseover) is just giving me the filepath of the thumbnail. Is that somehow binding the timer to the element?

Comment: The condition for the if is `if (loopEl)` - meaning if loopEl contains some value that is not zero, undefined, false, etc.  There is no bound element, you just operate on the one that is captured by loopEl (ie the thing that is being hovered)

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem, it works fine on the first thumbnail but speeds up for each subsequent thumbnail hovered over. There must be multiple timers running. Where would you call loopy(), after "loopEl = this" on mouseover?

Comment: Just call it once when the page loads.